# How do you account for gaps when using Min/Max in Access?

Tags: max, min, gaps-in-data

Good afternoon.

I work with parts application data for automobiles. Typically the data I work with will have the info listed individually by year. Sometimes I need to consolidate years using a query. Sometimes there will be year gaps and I do not know how to account for that.

> Year| Make | Model |PartNo |
>   2001|Toyota|Corolla|8675309|
>   2002|Toyota|Corolla|8675309|
>   2004|Toyota|Corolla|8675309|
>   2005|Toyota|Corolla|8675309|

There is no 2003. Using the Min and Max functions in a query I would get:

> Years  | Make | Model |PartNo |
>   2001-2005|Toyota|Corolla|8675309|

This would not be correct. The correct result would be:

> Years  | Make | Model |PartNo |
>   2001-2002|Toyota|Corolla|8675309|
>   2004-2005|Toyota|Corolla|8675309|

What would be the best way to get the data correctly?

Comment: You forgot to mention what you're talking about. Is this SQL? Excel? Matlab? Something else?

Comment: Sorry - I am using Access. I updated the question.